# Rails 5 dropping some keys in params which contains non null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I am moving from rails 3 to 5. I have a request to an API which accepts some parameter but is getting dropped in rails 5 for reasons I am not sure.
The params which I recieved in Rails 3 was as below:

```
params = {"Envelope" => {"Body" => {"notifications" => {"Notification" => {"id =>" XYZ, "sObject" => {"data1" => ABC, "data2" => PQR}}}}}, "action" => XXX, "controller" => YYY, "format" => "xml", "auth" => AUTH_TOKEN, "entity" => ENTITY_NAME}
```

Whereas in Rails 5, the params I am receiving is:

```
params = <ActionController::Parameters {"entity"=>ENTITY_NAME, "auth"=>AUTH_TOKEN,  "format"=>"xml", "controller"=> YYY, "action"=> XXX} permitted: false>
```

How are the parameters getting dropped when the request is made?

Answer (score 0):

The request was sending the body in XML format. Rails 3 parses the XML body by default to json but Rails 5 does not. actionpack-xml_parser gem has to be explicitly installed so that the request body is parsed.